# Compiling cURL for OS X 10.6.8 statically

Tags: macos, curl, command-line, compilation

I want to link to cURL with SSL in an XCode 3.2.6 project.

I downloaded cURL-7.29.0 and uncompressed it

I did:

`CFLAGS="-arch i386" ./configure --with-ssl=tmp/openssl/ --disable-shared --enable-static`

`make`

No errors, everything seems good however I dont see a `.a` file anywhere. Not even in `lib/`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until you hit `make install`, the actual compiled binary (well, rather archive) is kept by the config system in a hidden location: it's in `lib/.libs/libcurl.a`.

Comment: This may sound silly, but why is that this way? I dont usually run `make install` because I am building in the directory and I can easily  use it from that directory in my source tree.

Comment: @Jason That's because the GNU build system sucks. (Myself, I do prefer not to run `make install` as well... I just don't need it.)